# How do you change the "Size" text on the product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am really struggling to find where the "size" text is specified on the product page.

I have 3 stores and need to change this to be Size (UK), or Size (US).

Does anyone know where you change this?

Answer (score 0):

I would change it from translation file.

Go to your `app/locale/[your_language]/Mage_catalog` and add like this:

```
First Column    Second Column //these are csv columns.
"Size"          "Size([Your text])"
```

This should translate as you require.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for taking the time to reply. I have added this in and cleared the cache but unfortunately hasn't made any difference

Comment: Where is your text 'Size' appearing? Do you know in which file is it called?

Comment: <?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?> <em>*</em> in \default\template\configurableswatches\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable\swatches.phtml

Comment: I think you should add it in `Mage_adminhtml`. Since this is attribute and I think you haven't set Store view label for that.

Comment: thanks again, but still no joy